# While drawing in orthographic view, Is there any performance advantage of using glDrawElements

Tags: opengl

I am drawing some orthographic representations in bulk around one million in my model drawing.
(I will draw these things with some flag)

Camera is also implemented. rotation etc are possible.

All these orthograhic representations will change their positions when I rotate the model.
So that, it looks like, all these are in the same place on the model.

Now I would like to draw these orthographic things through graphics card, because, when these are huge in number, model rotation is very very slow.

I feel like there would not be any advantage, because, every time I have to recompute the postions based on the projection matrix.

1) Am I correct?

2) And also please let me know, how to improve performance when i am drawing bulk orthographic representations using opengl.

3) I also feel instancing will not work here, because for each orthographic rep is drawn between 2/3 positions. Am I correct ?

Comment: What are those "orthographic representations" like? Just something like textured quads, or do they have their own geometric representation each?

Comment: geometric representations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, OpenGL does the projection calculation for you while drawing: The positions handed over to GL are world or model coordinates, and GL rendering uses the model-view-projection matrix (while rendering) to calculate the screen coordinates for the current projection etc. If the camera moves, the only thing that changes is the MVP matrix handed to GL.

This shouldn't really depend on the kind of projection you are using. So I don't think you need to / should update the positions in your array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

You create a vertex buffer that contains each vertex position 6 times and 6 texture coordinates (that you need anyways if you want to draw your representation with textures) from which you make a quad in the vertex shader. In that you would emulate the openGL projection and then offset the vertex by its texture coordinate to create the quad with constant size.

When constructing the model:

```
vector<vec3>* positionList = new vector<vec3>();
vector<vec2>* texCoordList = new vector<vec2>();
for (vector<vec3>::iterator it = originalPositions->begin(); it != originalPositions->end(); ++it) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) //each quad consists of 2 triangles, therefore 6 vertices
    positionList->push_back(vec3(*it));

    texCoordList->push_back(vec2(0, 0)); //corresponding texture coordinates
    texCoordList->push_back(vec2(1, 0));
    texCoordList->push_back(vec2(0, 1));
    texCoordList->push_back(vec2(1, 0));
    texCoordList->push_back(vec2(1, 1));
    texCoordList->push_back(vec2(0, 1));
}
vertexCount = positionList->size();

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_Positions); //Generate the buffer for the vertex positions
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_Positions);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionList->size() * sizeof(vec3), positionList->data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO_texCoord); //Generate the buffer for texture coordinates, which we are also going to use as offset values
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO_texCoord);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordList->size() * sizeof(vec2), texCoordList->data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Vertex Shader:

```
void main() {
    fs_texCoord = vs_texCoord;

    vec4 transformed = (transform * vec4(vs_position, 1));
    transformed.xyz /= transformed.w; //This is how the openGL pipeline does projection

    vec2 offset = (vs_texCoord * 2 - 1) * offsetScale;
    //Map the texture coordinates from [0, 1] to [-offsetScale, offsetScale]

    offset.x *= invAspectRatio;

    gl_Position = vec4(transformed.xy + offset, 0, 1);
    //We pass the new position to the pipeline with w = 1 so openGL keeps the position we calculated
}
```

}

Note that you need to adapt to the aspect ratio yourself, since there is no actual orthogonal matrix in this that would do this for you, which is this line:

```
offset.x *= invAspectRatio;
```

Comment: So anyway again I have to compute something every time

Comment: The buffers need to be created only once when the model is loaded, all transformation is done one the graphics card in the vertex shader. Therefore, no permanent recalculating of points on the cpu needs to be performed.

Comment: but the position is always changing for orthographic representation